# Creating notes on the fly using Java Sound API. How to handle multiple notes?

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I'm using the Java Sound API and I know how to use a Sequencer for editing and performing tracks as well. My question now is how do I play multiple notes (not necessarily at the same time) on the fly correctly?

I used one track, added the MidiEvent NoteON and NoteOFF and then started the seuquencer to play the Note. On the second run I delete the previous events from the track and set the synthesizer to position 0 to start anew. That works fine.

The problem is that the previous notes will naturally be cut off even when their note off events are not fully executed therefore the note does not last as long as I wanted it to be.

Is the correct way to approach this via sending the note events to different tracks or are there better ways? The problem with this I encountered is, that starting the sequencer from position 0 will result in some previous notes being played again.

```
public void playSingleNote(int note, int velocity) throws InvalidMidiDataException, MidiUnavailableException {
        long tick = 0;
        sequencer.setTickPosition(0);// Start at beginning.
        // Clean track
        for (int i = 0; i < track.size(); i++) {
            track.remove(track.get(i));
        }

        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, note, velocity);
        MidiEvent evt = new MidiEvent(msg, tick);
        track.add(evt);

        msg = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, note, velocity);
        evt = new MidiEvent(msg, tick + 28);
        track.add(evt);

        sequencer.start();
    }
```

Comment: You could start with the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-messages.html

Comment: I don't think the sequencer is really appropriate for on-the-fly messages. It might be a better idea to send the notes directly to the receiver.

Comment: @gpasch Thank you thousand times for this post. Even though I read all the Java Tutorials regarding Java-Sound about 10 times each, I just left this one out for the reason that I did not really understand time stamps and the wire protocol!

Man I just send the Messages via MIDI Wire Protocol directly to the synthesizer and I have finally reached my goal! THANK YOU SO MUCH :D